# Sort data with GROUP_CONCAT and COUNT

Tags: mysql, count, group-concat

I have table `produk` and `transaksi_detail`

and then, I have two queries.

First query:

```
SELECT produk.idproduk, produk.nmproduk, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM produk, transaksi_detail
WHERE produk.idproduk=transaksi_detail.idproduk
GROUP BY produk.nmproduk
```

The result:

```
idproduk   |   nmproduk    |    total_order
-------------------------------------------
I3               coffe           6
I4               pencil          2
I1               bread           6
I2               snack           7
I5               tea             2
```

Second query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(produk.idproduk) AS idproduk, transaksi_detail.idtransaksi
FROM produk, transaksi_detail
WHERE produk.idproduk=transaksi_detail.idproduk
GROUP BY transaksi_detail.idtransaksi
```

The result:

```
idproduk   |   idtransaction
----------------------------
I2, I1, I5          1
I2, I4              2
I2, I3              3
I2, I1, I4          4
I1, I3              5
I2, I3              7
I1, I3              8
```

How to make result like the second result but "idproduk->GROUP_CONCAT" order by based on total_order in first query.
Like this :

```
 idproduk   |   idtransaction
----------------------------
I1, I2, I5          1
I4, I2              2
I3, I2              3
I4, I2, I1          4
I3, I1              5
I2, I3              7
I1, I3              8
```

"idproduk" The first from "I2" because total_order larger than the other 'desc'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(order_count.idproduk ORDER BY order_count.total DESC) AS idproduk, 
       transaksi_detail.idtransaksi 
FROM   (SELECT produk.idproduk, 
               COUNT(*) AS total 
        FROM   produk, 
               transaksi_detail 
        WHERE  produk.idproduk = transaksi_detail.idproduk 
        GROUP  BY produk.nmproduk) order_count 
       INNER JOIN transaksi_detail 
               ON order_count.idproduk = transaksi_detail.idproduk 
GROUP BY transaksi_detail.idtransaksi
```